# Some strange behavior of the UI?

Tags: android, user-interface, alignment

This is the static xml that I have:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/Header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        android:background="@drawable/header_bg"
        android:padding="0dp"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/hLogo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hActiveCategory"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Today"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/hRefreshButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/refresh"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:padding="0dp"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

What is happening? - when I try to align ***Button*** with *id=hRefreshButton* to the Right of its parent (***RelativeLayout*** with *id=Header*) there is still space between the button and the right bound of the screen. Why this is happening? Any suggestions? Also I have to emphasize that I'm testing on AVD emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button is getting right aligned with respect to parent (Relative Layout) but because of the default background you may see some space left on the right side of the button.

Try setting the background to some image or set background color, you will see for yourself.

Shash

Comment: I tried it, but it does not work. Also I don't think this is the problem, why I think so - if that you're saying was true, then the relative layout should have the same space between its right bound and the right bound of the screen. I see where is the problem, but don't know how to fix it and it is in the **Button**, because when I say `android:background="@drawable/refresh"`, there is not such a space left. There is some default property of the UI component **Button**, which cause it.

Comment: The default background is like that. Since you have given wrap content, you ll get border kind of effect. Basically default background is button pic + transparent padding. Set background to #00000000, you ll not see the padding

Comment: Ok, if it's true, why I do not get this transparent padding at the Top of the Button (actually the question should be - why it is not all around the button) and it's just at the Left of it.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but is there a way to remove this transparent padding without setting `android:background` property?

Comment: That is because the default drawable for Button view has right and bottom padding.

Comment: Now a fully understand the situation, thanks for the explanation!